# How to convert a python timedelta to a string that has a leading zero so it retains the format "00:00:00" (%HH:%MM:%SS)

Tags: python, string, datetime, datetime-format, timedelta

Given a timedelta in python such as:

```
td = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
```

if printed as a string it appears without the leading zero I want:

```
t_str = string(td)
print(t_str)
# result: "0:10:00"
```

How can I convert it to a string that retains the format of "00:10:00" (%HH:%MM:%SS)?

Comment: 10 minutes is an example; the solution needs to scale to keep the format consistent for any given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit tricky, because the behaviour for negative values as well as values longer than a day is more complicated.

```
def str_td(td):
    s = str(td).split(", ", 1)
    a = s[-1]
    if a[1] == ':':
        a = "0" + a
    s2 = s[:-1] + [a]
    return ", ".join(s2)

print(str_td(datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)))
print(str_td(datetime.timedelta(minutes=3200)))
print(str_td(datetime.timedelta(minutes=-1400)))
print(str_td(datetime.timedelta(seconds=4003.2)))
print(str_td(datetime.timedelta(seconds=86401.1)))
```

gives

```
00:10:00
2 days, 05:20:00
-1 day, 00:40:00
01:06:43.200000
1 day, 00:00:01.100000
```

A completely different way of doing it would be

```
def str_td(td):
    s = str(td).split(", ", 1)
    t = datetime.time(td.seconds // 3600,td.seconds // 60 % 60,td.seconds % 60, td.microseconds)
    s2 = s[:-1] + [str(t)]
    return ", ".join(s2)

print(str_td(datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)))
print(str_td(datetime.timedelta(minutes=3200)))
print(str_td(datetime.timedelta(minutes=-1400)))
print(str_td(datetime.timedelta(seconds=4003.2)))
print(str_td(datetime.timedelta(seconds=86401.1)))
```

which gives the same result as above.

Which one is more elegant is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I thought I was missing something useful regarding time formatting in python, but if it's a matter of string manipulation I might be okay with `if len(t_str) < 8: t_str = '0'+t_str`.

Comment: @Jaydog But your simple solution doesn't fulfill "the solution needs to scale to keep the format consistent for any given time".

Comment: I understand, good spot @glglgl. Simple solution would indeed be limited to whole seconds, and issue with days is a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
"{:0>8}".format(str(td))
# result: "00:10:00"
```

Comment: See issue raised by glglgl which affects this approach.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `time` and then format using the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) method.

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.time(0, 10, 0)

dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
td = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
time = '0'+str(td)
print(time)
```

The output is

```
00:10:00
```

Comment: Yes, simplest approach is to hardcode it using strings:
`if len(t_str) < 8: t_str = '0'+t_str`

Comment: @Jaydog But what about the issue with the microseconds and the days? Both make the string longer, without fulfilling the required condition.

Answer (score 0):

for less than 24 hours work well

```
print(str(datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)).zfill(8))

"00:10:00"
```

when you exceed 24 hours, it looks like

```
print(str(datetime.timedelta(minutes=1445)).zfill(8))

"1 day, 0:05:00"
```